# MYSQL IFNULL is not working

Tags: mysql

MYSQL:

```
SELECT `item`.*,
       IFNULL(cart.Item, Item.ID) AS Button
FROM `item`
LEFT JOIN `cart` ON `cart`.`Item` = `item`.`ID`
AND `cart`.`User` = 3
GROUP BY `item`.`ID`
ORDER BY `item`.`ID`;
```

Anyone can please tell me why IFNULL function is not working in this SQL; statement How can I resolve this?

Comment: It must be IS NULL FIELDNAME not IF NULL

Comment: You have a group by without any aggregation functions the result set will be indeterminate. BTW ifnull works but I guess the item.id is null.

Comment: *is not working*  is no error description

Comment: If you simply have an empty column that's not the same as `NULL`. Please show your database structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of `IFNULL` function
because `IFNULL()`may produce errors if both `cart.item` and `item.id` are null.

```
SELECT `item`.*,
IF(cart.Item is null, Item.ID, cart.Item) AS Button
FROM `item`
LEFT JOIN `cart` ON `cart`.`Item` = `item`.`ID`
AND `cart`.`User` = 3
GROUP BY `item`.`ID`
ORDER BY `item`.`ID`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may  use the COALESCE() function, like this:

```
SELECT `item`.*,  COALESCE(cart.Item, Item.ID) AS Button
```

This will return the second argument Item.ID  when cart.item is NULL